# Flask with gunicorn on nginx 502 bad gateway error

Tags: python, ubuntu, nginx, flask, gunicorn

After some ubuntu 16.04 upgrades and app code modifications, my Flask on gunicorn and nginx website which previously was working is now giving a 502 bad gateway error.

myapp.conf:

```
upstream app_server_wsgiapp {
  server localhost:8000 fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name www.myserver.com;

  access_log   /var/log/nginx/www.myapp.access.log;
  error_log   /var/log/nginx/www.myapp.error.log info;
  keepalive_timeout    5;

  location /static {
    autoindex on;
    alias /myapp/static;
  }

  location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    if (!-f $request_filename) {
      proxy_pass http://app_server_wsgiapp;
      break; 
    }
    client_max_body_size 2097152;
    #to get around upstream sent too big header while reading response header from upstream error
    proxy_buffer_size          128k;
    proxy_buffers              4 256k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size    256k;
  }

  # this section allows Nginx to reverse proxy for websockets
  location /socket.io {
    proxy_pass http://app_server_wsgiapp/socket.io;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
  } 
}
```

/var/log/nginx/myapp.error.log

```
2017/06/11 06:42:52 [error] 31054#31054: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: clientip, server: www.myserver.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/", host: "www.myapp.com"
```

From my apps log file I note that Flask gets part of the way through starting up, then restarts in a continuous fail/restart loop.

Any ideas how I can go about debugging what could be causing this issue?

Comment: How did you start the flask service? Have you tried to run the flask service in interactive mode and check the console output?

Comment: @hzm I am deploying and starting flask via an ansible deploy script which sets up gunicorn then uses supervisor to restart nginx. It's non-trivial to start this flask setup manually on server, will keep hacking away at it

Comment: @hzm you're a legend, can you put your comment in an answer please - by manually starting the app on the server I picked up a dependency issue and the app was creashing out each time, then supervisor was just restarting it. All fixed now

Comment: answer added :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the problem is caused by flask app running error. Could you please try to run the app in interactive way? With same params and environment settings in daemon way and check whether the service can be started correctly?